# Scala pattern matching: How to match on an element inside a list?

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

Is it possible to rewrite the following code using Scala pattern matching?

```
val ls: List[String] = ??? // some list of strings

val res = if (ls.contains("foo")) FOO
     else if (ls.contains("bar")) BAR
     else SOMETHING_ELSE
```

Comment: UPDATE: The list is short (up to 4 or 5 items) and can only contain one of the seeking values. A list actually represents a path in a tree like structure. I want to identify which sub-tree the path addresses. So I'm looking for a specific node in a path and if found I return an identifier of that sub tree. The problem is that the nodes I am seeking can be on different levels in a tree, so I don't know if it's gonna be 1st, 2rd or 4th element in a path (a list).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could implement this using a function like

```
def onContains[T](xs: Seq[String], actionMappings: (String, T)*): Option[T] = {
  actionMappings collectFirst {
    case (str, v) if xs contains str => v
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val x = onContains(items,
  "foo" -> FOO,
  "bar" -> BAR
)
```

Comment: thanks for answer. What does the * mean in `actionMappings: (String, T)*`?

Comment: It allows to define a method to have a variable number of arguments which can be accessed as a `Seq` collection. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/functions_variable_arguments.htm

Answer (score 21):

You can add `if` conditions to matches like this:

```
ls match {
  case x if x.contains("foo") => // FOO
  case x if x.contains("bar") => // BAR
  case _ => // ELSE
}
```

However, it is not the nicest way, as each `if` check needs to traverse the list, so this doesn't scale well. There are various different ways to deal with this problem, but we would need to know more about your intensions, as normally the runtime semantics would differ from your code (for example, you could recursively traverse the list looking for either "foo" or "bar", but that would assume you only have either one in the list).

Comment: I thought did it that way but 'case' looks redundant as I have those 'if's anyway.
I would want to write something like { case _ :: "foo" :: _ => ??? }

Answer (score 2):

As Frank's answer says, it is possible, but expensive if you would do it the dirty way.

It depends on what you want to do. Do you want to return the index of that "foo" or "bar" (for example)? Then you would do something like this:

```
def indexOf[T]: (List[T], T) => Int = (ls, x) => ls match {
    case Nil => -1
    case e::es if( e.equals(x) ) => 0
    case e::es => val i = indexOf( es, x ); if( i < 0 ) i else i + 1
}
```

This code is not tested, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is some sort of *command execution with prioritization* I can suggest

```
def executeCommand(input: List[String]): Option[Unit] = {

  val priorities = Map(
    "foo" -> 1,
    "bar" -> 2,
    "baz" -> 3) withDefault(_ => 4)

  def extractCommand(cmds: List[String]): Option[String] = 
    (cmds sortBy priorities).headOption

  extractCommand(input) map {
    case "foo" => println("found foo")
    case "bar" => println("found bar")
    case "baz" => println("found baz")
    case _     => println("no known command")
  }

}
```

In this specific implementation no meaningful result is returned (you only go for side effects), but if your cases should return some value, you would find it wrapped in an `Option` as the method result.

---

**UPDATED**
*based on your additional comment*

```
def execute(input: List[String]): Option[String] = {
  val commands: PartialFunction[String, String] = {
    case "foo" => "result for foo"
    case "bar" => "result for bar"
    case "baz" => "result for baz"
  }

  (input find commands.isDefinedAt) map commands

}
```

This works only if your commands are exclusive, only one should be in the `input` List

Comment: Yes my cases should return a value (see my comment to the question). I like your approach, although it is much  less concise than simple if-else construction. But I would need to have my constants (foo, bar, baz etc) to be listed twice in a code. I have a couple of dozens of them so I would avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
val ls = List[String]("bar", "foo", "baz")  // stuff to check against
val mappy = Map[String, String]("foo" -> "FOO", "bar" -> "BAR")  // conversions go here

val res = ls.flatMap{
  case x: String => mappy.get(x)
} match {
  case Seq(y) => y
  case Nil => "SOMETHING_ELSE"  // the `else` case goes here
  case _ => new Exception("could be more than one thing")  // handle this however you want
}
```

I believe this to be the most Scalaesque way to do it. The relationship between the cases and their results is concisely stated in the `Map`, and you have the option of dealing with multiple results however you want. You did say

> The list is short (up to 4 or 5 items) and can only contain one of the seeking values

But some may need to deal with that possibility. If you really, really don't care about multiple matches, you can do

```
val res = ls.flatMap(mappy.get).headOption.getOrElse("SOMETHING_ELSE")
```

In either case, it traverses the list only once. Enjoy!