# How to match on list element

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, case, scala-collections

I want to match whether the list contains a certain element, and return different results according to the different elements. I wrote it in if else way, now I want to write it in match case, but I am not very familiar with match case, can anyone help me write case matching way, thank you

Below is the code for if else

```
   val sten=List(sort_view.head._1,sort_view(1)._1)
  if(sten.contains("Positive")) println("Positive")
  else if (sten.contains("Neutral")) println("Neutral")
  else if (sten.contains("Negative")) println("Negative")
  else if (sten.contains("Verynegative")) println("Verynegative")
```

Comment: Try looking into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643567/scala-pattern-matching-how-to-match-on-an-element-inside-a-list

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the answer I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter and get the first result:

```
List("Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", "Verynegative")
    .filter(sten.contains)
    .headOption
    .foreach(println)
```

It's easier and cleaner than pattern matching in this case.